# Is DefinitelyTyped appropriate for new TypeScript definitions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/:

> DefinitelyTyped will still be the place to author new declaration
>   files.

But it's unclear why we'd create new definitions at DefinitelyTyped as opposed to submitting them directly to NPM.

Being that DT is so large now, it seems counter productive to continue adding to that repo. What are the advantages of DT over publishing to NPM directly?

Comment: What does 'submitting them directly to NPM' mean to you?

Comment: I was considering creating a github repo for the definition (it's for a third party js library that doesn't have their own definition), along with with all the requisite files for supporting NPM. I'd then publish it as a new NPM package under @types.

Comment: Can you even publish to the @types org without going through DefinitelyTyped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DefinitelyTyped repo is being treated as the endorsed community repository of type declarations **for packages that don't provide their own**.

Answering this question depends on what you mean when you say

> submitting them directly to NPM.

If you mean **including the .d.ts file with the package** that the .d.ts file corresponds to that's encouraged. The [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) package, for example, includes and maintains its own declaration file.

If you mean **providing your own type only package** then DefinitelyTyped is the better location for those files and will provide some advantages. By including your file in DefinitelyTyped it will

- benefit from automated deploys to the [@types namespace](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) by the TS typings bot.

  - which will also yield predictable module resolution in the compiler.
- be in the long established source for typings. You'll be where people are looking.
- be more easily maintained by others.

  - the package will be easier to find
  - maintainers will use a workflow and format they're familiar with

Comment: 1) NPM package submission is easy to automate. Not sure how module resolution factors in to that. 2) People shouldn't look in DT for typings. They should look in typesearch. Additionally, NPM will link directly to the definition repo.  3) DT is no more easily maintained than another GH repo.

Sorry for the confusion. Just trying to get the ultimate answer.

Comment: 1) I could be mistaken here, but I don't believe you can publish to the @types organization yourself. If you were to publish elsewhere, you'd need to manually make TSC aware of your .d.ts file by including it in the compile file list or using the typeRoots option to specify a secondary location. 2) typesearch uses DT. My understanding is typesearch exists to find packages DT that aren't named the same as their npm counterpart, not to find all .d.ts files period. 3) Their tooling is in general going to be more sophisticated, their requirements more consistent, and again they'll have visibility.

Comment: 3 cont'd) You may be individually be able to maintain a .d.ts package at as high a level as we'd expect from DT, but your package won't be as visible to others. Overall I'd say you'd be suffering a lot of friction you wouldn't need to @AlexDresko

Comment: Ahhhh, now we're getting somewhere. You hit on a lot of points that I don't think have been made obvious elsewhere. I'd love to get some kind of confirmation from @RyanCavanaugh, I think this is the answer I'm looking for. Most surprising is the hypothesis that not everyone can publish to (@)types on NPM. That alone is reason enough to go with DT.

Comment: @AlexDresko I started with TS and cared about npm only as much as I had to so I'm not entirely confident on the rights involved but from what I understand orgs are set up and maintained by a closed group who have access to publish to them. I'm not seeing any indication that you'd be able to unless you were a member of the organization. Given what I'm seeing from the description of orgs and the recommendation to post to DT whenever the types question comes up I figured you couldn't. It's an assumption, but it feels like a safe one. But by all means Ryan would be much more of an authority here.

Comment: @AlexDresko just for fun I created a test org in NPM and scrolled through the [org documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/docs/orgs/). I don't see how I could allow access for all npm users. Not conclusive, but compelling

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile. I didn't even know what an NPM org was until you brought it up -- I thought it was just a package naming convention. Interestingly, I noticed that as of today, NPM orgs are now free. No word on whether or not they plan on relaxing org permissions for anonymous publishing as a result of this change.  If orgs one day allow anonymous publishing, it would make sense for type search to pull from that as opposed to DT.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Paarth's answer, being in DefinitelyTyped provides extra benefits you should consider:

- Automatic version tags for older TypeScript language versions. If you ship your definition file in your own package, then you and your consumers have to agree on which version of TypeScript to use. If it's on DefinitelyTyped, as you update the definition file, the `@types` publisher will automatically tag the latest compatible release for older TS versions (e.g. people on TS 2.1 can `npm install @types/yourpkg@ts2.1` to get a 2.1-compatible version)
- Free maintenance from the DefinitelyTyped maintainers. Often DT can find definition file bugs by writing new TSLint rules and applying them across the entire codebase
- Better versioning - you can more easily provide side-by-side definitions for multiple versions of your library, and version these independently of the underlying library

Comment: Senpai noticed me

Comment: IMO these don't seem like strong reasons, less I'm misunderstanding something. 1) Installing a version based on your TS version _is_ nice, but you NPM's ability to install from any tag or branch can enable the same functionality if the repo is designed to support it. 2) If my package is on GH, anyone can contribute. Repo-wide linting is nice, though. 3) My first point covers this, no? 

Sorry for the confusion. Just trying to get the ultimate answer.

Comment: Here's a thought experiment: You write a .d.ts file for v3.0.3 of your library. You realize you made a mistake in the definition file (misspelling a property name, for example). Should you publish a fix at v3.x.x? Common sense says yes, mistakes should be fixed. But semver says no, because a .d.ts file change is almost never guaranteed to be backward compatible. Now you're stuck and have to rev your entire library up a major version, even if you didn't want to.

Comment: There are many things you can do to a definition that won't affect backward compatibility. For example: adding a new interface, method, or override. Fixing a bug usually doesn't negatively affect backward compatibility, since the bug was likely preventing a developer from using the definition in the first place. I'm sorry, but I don't understand what any of that has to do with DT.

Comment: Adding a type is not a semver compatible change because your definition could conflict with a user type in the same namespace. Adding a new method is not a semver compatible change because it breaks compilation of existing mocks. etc. etc.

Comment: Oh, you and your completely valid edge cases, you... :) Great response. Can you confirm or deny the statements/assumptions made by @paarth in his last comment?

Comment: It's all correct as far as I can see. One thing I should add is that in the near future, trusted maintainers (i.e. lib authors or experts) will be able to have their PRs to DT auto-merged to reduce friction

Comment: I forgot about that friction aspect. We have a lot of homegrown definitions for 3rd party libraries in-house, because 1) we didn't have the answers to the OP, and 2) we sometimes don't have the liberty of waiting for the PR+merge+publisher process to complete. Guess I'll have to prove myself worthy of being a trusted maintainer soon. :) Both answers here are great, but I'm leaning towards @paarth's answer. That being said, there's some good information on this page -- is there someone who can update the docs, or should I create a PR for that?